# nginx + wordpress server name in permalinks

Tags: wordpress, nginx, permalinks

I just moved my webste to another server and after installing nginx + php5-fpm I noticed a strange permalink structure. The server name is repeated in the permalink structure.

Example:

www.myserver.com/myserver.com/%postname%-%day%%monthnum%
These are the rewrite rules I would like to use wordpress shows me to add to .htaccess (which I cannot use because it is nginx.) There is this error in RewriteBase, I beleive it should be just a "/"" there, instead it shows me that:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myserver.com/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /myserver.com/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

My nginx.conf looks like this:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    # multi_accept on;
}


http {
    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 2;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    #access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log off;
 client_max_body_size   128M;
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/css text/javascript text/xml text/plain text/x-component application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json application/xml  application/rss+xml font/truetype application/x-font-ttf font/opentype application/vnd.ms-fontobject image/svg+xml;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##
    index index.php;
    ## See here: http://wiki.nginx.org/WordPress

    server {
        ## Your IP number goes here:
        listen  XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;


 rewrite ^/wp-content/w3tc/min/([a-f0-9]+)\/(.+)\.(include(\-(footer|body))?(-nb)?)\.[0-9]+\.(css|js)$ /wp-content/w3tc/min/index.php?tt=$1&gg=$2&g=$3&t=$7 last;
        ## Your website name goes here.
        server_name myserver.com;
        ## Your only path reference.
            root /var/www/myserver.com;

                location /phpmyadmin {
           root /usr/share/;
           index index.php index.html index.htm;
           location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
                   try_files $uri =404;
                   root /usr/share/;
                   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                   fastcgi_index index.php;
                   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                   include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
           }
           location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
                   root /usr/share/;
           }
    }
            location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
        }

            location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
        }

            location / {
            # This is cool because no php is touched for static content
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;    
        }

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress check for Apache mod_rewrite, WP needs it to work properly with permalinks, dixit the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx)

If you want to get it works the easier is to use the Nginx_helper plugin, you can find it here : https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nginx-helper/

In the codex linked before will you will find all the config files you need to make Wordpress works with Nginx !

Hope it helps!

Comment: hi, it helped but I found out it was a problem related to wordpress itself, I had to change the wordpress URL (actually I just retyped the address) and the error was gone.